# The particle へ in 山へ面している

Tags: grammar, verbs, particle-に, particle-を, particle-へ

**tl;dr**: Should `へ` be replaced with `に` here?

I was reading [Imabi](https://www.imabi.net/) and found the following example:

> 小屋は山へ面している。

As far as I know, `へ` is used with motion verbs especially when transition from one (current) location to the destination (marked by `へ`) occurs:

> A particle that indicates the direction toward which some directional movement or action proceeds.
>   (*A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar*)

Why do the author of Imabi use this particle in this particular situation if the word `[面]{めん}する` means *to front/to face smth*?

I know another particle that can be translated as "towards" — `を`, but according to Imabi it requires an *action* verb, what (in my opinion) the `[面]{めん}する` is not.

Another particle which can mark direction is `に`, which can replace `へ` in most cases. `に` can also mark indirect objects, so I believe it is the best candidate to replace `へ`.

**FYI**: This example is Ex. 18 in [第36課: ～ている](https://www.imabi.net/teiru.htm)

Answer (score 1):

[BCCWJ](https://pj.ninjal.ac.jp/corpus_center/bccwj/en/) has **1100** instances of `に面し`/`に面す` but **no** instances of `へ面し`/`へ面す`, so you should always use に. That said, we can still find some examples of ～へ面していて on Google, and I personally feel they are not awfully bad. Meaning-wise, I see no difference.

Comment: So the grammatically correct variant is `に`, the however usage of `へ` will not lead to misunderstanding?

Thanks for BCCWJ, it's quite useful.